# How do I link a react build from my main html

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new to web development and I created a react app and built it.  I renamed the index.html to react.html.  In my main index.html I has this link.

```
a  href="react.html">react</a>
```

When I click it it just gets a blank page.  Is there some better way that works?  I also put the index.html into the build file.

Comment: When on the blank page and right click and inspect source. Is there anything? More than likely the href= route is not correct so it cannot find the file react.html.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any id, like `id="root"` or `id="app"` or something where the react app will render something?